# Sum of filtered group in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have applied Top N filter on 'Purchase_Amount' group so that i can get only Top N values of group but when i am applying Sum on group

```
=Sum(Fields!Purchase.Value, "Purchase_Amount")
```

that give me sum of 
whole dataset so how can i get sum of filtered group ?

Comment: 'Purchase_Amount' is group and i have applied filter on that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to address this. I would probable move the filter up the data stream, either into the query, or into the Dataset properties.

But some two other methods are described in [this MSDN Community thread:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/0b21bab0-ff02-4655-a69c-efedfb2a7077)
Either creating a fake total row within the group members that contains the `=RunningValue(...)` function, and set the visibility to only show on the last row; or refer to another page item where you can get just the total of your filtered items.

Comment: Moved tablix filter upstream to dataset filter.  Total calculations are improved.

Answer (score 12):

You could try setting the filter on your tablix instead of the group - any sums in the tablix are then subject to that filter.

[image: Tablix Properties]